# Naming process in init scripts

Tags: centos, init-script

I'm trying to write an init script that will start a service that needs to have started `postgresql` server before. Bellow is the `postgresql`'s init header:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# postgresql    This is the init script for starting up the PostgreSQL
#               server.
#
# chkconfig: - 64 36
# description: PostgreSQL database server.
# processname: postmaster
# pidfile: /var/run/postmaster-9.1.pid
```

In the header from my init script, how should I refer to postgresql, through `postgresql-9.1` (the init script file name) or through `postmaster` (that's because of `processname` from `postgresql`'s init script)?